# Как лучше реализовать сайт с поиском по динамическим выпадающим спискам?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

Есть база данных на 8000 комбинаций (строк), пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сделать сайт-подсказку, пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где в динамическом варианте через выпадающий список человек выбирает сначала продукт, потом способ приготовления (из возможных для данного продукта), потом вес продукта (из возможных для данного продукта) в финальном варианте погружается температура приготовления и время, если есть отзыв то и отзыв.

Делаю для мобильной и десктопной версии. Желательно чтобы это быстро грузилось как никак 8000 строк.

Как лучше реализовать? Может на wp через плагины или может вообще без CMS на чистом коде? Или есть какие нибудь готовые решения?

Comment: 80000 ничто, все будет работать быстро

Comment: Выберайте тот инструмент, которым владеете

Comment: Нашел решение. Реализовать это с помощью зависимых выпадающих списков [Тут подробно как это сделать](https://webformyself.com/zavisimye-spiski-select-s-pomoshhyu-ajax-chast-1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно делать из-под водпресса, у вас ведь не 8000 комбинаций под каждую позицию. Делаете посттипы и регистрируете wp_ajax, при выборе значения из селекта отправляете запрос на сервер, в обрабатываете в wp_query, возвращаемый результат подставляете в следующий селект и так далее. Отрабатывать будет быстро, wp_ajax не грузит кучу лишнего кода с шаблона и т.д, главное запросы правильно построить. Подробнее о wp_ajax читайте здесь https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Answer (score 2):

Что касается WordPress то можно сделать так:

1. Создать пост тип с дополнительными метаполями
2. Использоватьстандартный шаблон search.php
3. Заморочится и сделать ajax)

Но в целом вордпресс для этого слишком тяжелый)

Comment: Спасибо, уже наше решение.